# Terminology question around "slot filling"

Tags: chat-bots

This is a question about terminology.

Assume you have a chatbot with intent classification and slot filling. Assume you have an intent to handle questions about shops in a town. A user asks a questions like "Do you have shops in London" and as a response it should list the shops in London if there are any. Now 'London' is a city, the city is an entity that has to be extracted and in slot filling this is assigned to the parameter 'city' for the operation to find a list of shops.

Now assume the user asks "Do you have shops in my town". Now the entity of the city is missing. With an additional prompt you can ask the user what it his town. Assume you treat this in the very same intent and you want to fill the slot of the parameter 'city' is then the operation where you ask the user for the city part of the 'slot filling'? If not what would be the proper name for this operation?

Comment: Where did you find this term "slot filling"? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Actually by exposure in interaction with a group of software engineers that have been referring to this term.
Myself I had a look at https://medium.com/geekculture/intent-classification-and-slot-filling-managing-web-pages-with-natural-language-4d21d5cee4e3 and got the impression "slot filling" should only be used for the automatic ML part, not for the process of asking the user to provide missing information.